# How do I include jQuery library in BIRT

Tags: javascript, jquery, birt

I'm trying to include jQuery library in BIRT report, I tried two ways:

1. I tried to use an text element which properties is HTML and dynamic text in the report, and I copied `jQuery.js` code into the `<script></script>` snippet, it does work for few simple operations, but it does not work as jQuery should
2. So I suspect that it should be included in the `<head>` tag, and then I modified the below files:

   `birt/webcontent/birt/pages/layout\FramesetFragment.jsp`
   `birt/webcontent/birt/pages/layout\RequesterFragment.jsp`
   `birt/webcontent/birt/pages/layout\RunFragment.jsp`

to include `jquery.js`, but it doesn't work either

Any idea?

Comment: How about this: http://www.birt-exchange.org/org/forum/index.php/topic/21499-javascript-jquery-in-birt-report/

Answer (score 2):

I've done this two different ways.

The first and easiest is to include an html text element at the top of your report so it's read first with a pointer to your jquery library:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
```

This is still in the BODY of your page, but as long as it's up above everything else, it should still be read first.

The second way is to use a modified HTML emitter that allows you to add elements to the HEAD portion of your HTML page.  This is available [here](http://www.birt-exchange.org/org/devshare/designing-birt-reports/1490-modified-birt-html-emitter/) and was written by johnw.  It requires you to modify the jar files in your birt engine.